# How to assign a number per cell?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I assign numbers to a list, for each cell, starting from number 1 ?

Here are my data :

[image]

and when delete or add cell number reset dynamic

There is my code :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var allUsers = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(allUsers, id: \.self) { user in
                HStack {
                    Text("1")
                    Text(user)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ForEach` like bellow

```
ForEach(0..<allUsers.count) { indexNumber in
    HStack {
        Text("\(indexNumber + 1)")
        Text(self.allUsers[indexNumber])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about…

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var allUsers = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(allUsers, id: \.self) { user in
                HStack {
                    // Adding 1 here as the index function returns 0 for the first index
                    Text("\(allUsers.index(of: user)! + 1)")
                    Text(user)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```